# Where does fish_config save its settings?

Tags: shell, fish

I've used the `fish_config` utility to customize my syntax color scheme and now I want to copy these settings to remote servers I can't run `fish_config` on. Where does it save the changes made through that utility?

Comment: I believe as universal variables. Do `set -U` to see them

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some settings, such as the color theme, are stored as universal variables. Run `set -U` to see them.

Note that at the moment universal variables are stored in a file whose name is unique to each host. In the upcoming fish 3.0.0 release we're going to make that file truly global so that simply copying your `~/.config/fish` directory tree to another machine will install items like your color theme. See [this issue](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1912) for more details.

At the moment you need to use `set -U | grep fish_color_` on the machine having the theme you like and do `set -U` of each var on the target machine. A bit of a pain in the ass we admit.

The prompt is saved as an autoloaded function in `~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish`.

Comment: Following up, since version 3, everything is stored in `~/.config/fish/fish_variables`.